# Simulate click - enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme

I have a problem with Enzyme tool to test React app.

In my component I have login form and I want to test if after click on button the p tag will fill by text.

In fact after clicking submit there is sent request to the api (which doesn't exist now), the error about unreachable endpoint is returned.

Tried to test it in a lot of ways, but noticed one funny thing. Using:

```
it('returns error if endpoint not reachable', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<LoginForm dispatch={dispatch} store={store} />);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
```

returns HTML code in console. But there p tag is also not filled. So my question is how to use simulate function here?

First time I thought it is caused by some timeout. But using setTimeout gives the same result.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enzyme gives the ability to submit a click event.  If it's not working i'm curious if you have the right element selected.  An example from the docs...

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md#example

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={`clicks-${count}`}>
          {count} clicks
        </div>
        <a href="url" onClick={() => { this.setState({ count: count + 1 }); }}>
          Increment
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);

expect(wrapper.find('.clicks-0').length).to.equal(1);
wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
expect(wrapper.find('.clicks-1').length).to.equal(1);
```

So in your particular case you mentioned an API call is made after clicking the submit button.  You'll need to isolate and mock this behavior using something like Sinon.

http://sinonjs.org/